# Can IIS be configured to use local server when internet connection is not available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, iis-express, iis-8

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC app, the requirement here is the user wants to have the app both online and as local as well in sync, so when the internet connection is not available the domain redirects the users to the local server and when the internet connection comes back try to use the online version with sync of local server data to the online one, the question here is there any workaround to check for internet connectivity in IIS to determine the domain name redirects the user to online or offline version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then deploy a reverse proxy there and let all user browsers to pull contents from there. Reverse proxy solutions can be configured to query different upstream servers and locate the best to serve web contents, and in your case the remote and local servers are just two upstreams. How to define the actual strategy is not hard if you check user manuals. This is more of a networking question, not programming related.

Comment: @LexLi I totally agree that's more of the networking question than programming, but still it needs IIS configuration which is programming related as I'm hosting the website on IIS on both the servers (local - remote), I assume what you mean is to configure IIS to use reverse proxy or I misunderstood?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think IIS reverse proxy (upon ARR) has active-passive support, so another solution like nginx might be the direction you go.